# How to get queries by a user group

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to get all queries run by users in a specific user group for a Redshift database. Here's the query I'm running:

```
select
  q.*,
  u.usename,
  swq.total_queue_time / 1000000 as queue_time
from stl_query q
  inner join pg_user u on q.userid = u.usesysid
  inner join pg_group g on u.usesysid = ANY (g.grolist)
  inner join stl_wlm_query swq on q.query = swq.query
where q.userid <> 1
      AND database = 'mydb'
      AND g.groname = 'ops'
order by q.starttime desc;
```

However, I'm getting `Column "g.grolist" has unsupported type "integer[]"`. I've tried other forms of the same query (e.g., putting the `ANY` condition in `WHERE`), but I keep getting the same error. How can I check whether a user ID occurs in the list of user IDs in `pg_group`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this redshift [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html) having `array` types included in the unsupported list of PostgresSQL data types, and that's causing your SQL error of `column has unsupported type`.

Redshift is not exactly Postgres & thus doesn't have full feature support for all Postgres data types and functions. So refering redshift guide for any errors/differences in behaviour you encounter will be the best bet.

> Find out more differences here: [Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)

For unsupported data types, it states:

> If a query attempts to use an unsupported data type, including explicit or implicit casts, it will return an error.

However redshift does support some `array` & `json-array` function(s) which you can use to play with array column type. Like below query will output your desired result using `array_to_string`.

```
select
  q.*,
  u.usename,
  swq.total_queue_time / 1000000 as queue_time
from stl_query q
  inner join pg_user u on q.userid = u.usesysid
  inner join pg_group g on array_to_string(g.grolist,',') like '%' || u.usesysid || '%'
  inner join stl_wlm_query swq on q.query = swq.query
where q.userid <> 1
      AND database = 'mydb'
      AND g.groname = 'ops'
order by q.starttime desc;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. `u.usesysid` is an integer whereas `g.grolist` is an integer[]. `operator does not exist: integer = integer[];`

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: Not really. I still don't know how to get all queries by users in a group. I understand Redshift doesn't have arrays. Although that's weird since `pg_group` is technically a Redshift table.

Comment: I have updated the post with the workable query to get the desired result.